# Which firewall ports have to be open for a DLNA client running on Ubuntu?

Tags: rhythmbox, totem, dlna

Which firewall ports have to be open for a DLNA client running on Ubuntu?

I have found incoming restrictive rules to be a show stopper for the DLNA discovery service on a client machine running Ubuntu. Which ports have to be open for the client DLNA discovery service? I am using Grilo plugin for both Totem and Rhythmbox.

EDIT: With DLNAautoAddports.sh following Rhythmbox and Totem start script is working:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
a=0
for i in `seq 1 15`;
do

    sudo ./DLNAAutoAddPorts.sh;sleep 0.1
    if [ "$a" = "0" ]; then
        rhythmbox&        
        a=1
    fi      

    echo $i
done
```

Contens of DLNAAutoAddPorts.sh is [here](https://github.com/PartialVolume/DLNAAutoAddPorts).

Comment: have you tried it with vlc?

Comment: Yes, the same result. When I switch off the firewall, the network discovery for dlna works. My ufw settings are outgoing traffic allow, incoming traffic refuse except outbound connections. I tried to open ports 1900 and 8200, but that is not sufficient. The dlna discovery needs some additional ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use different DLNA servers, ie bubbleupnp, minidlna & rygel however they all suffer the same issue.

So I wrote a program that takes care if it. You may find it useful, I've tested with Rhythmbox but not totem, if you fancy giving it a go let me know whether it worked for you.

It basically monitors your DLNA programs and opens the ports they require subject to a few appropriate limitations.

The script can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/PartialVolume/DLNAAutoAddPorts)

Update: I've loaded Rhythmbox and enabled the Grilo package and I can access other DLNA servers on the LAN without any problems. The DLNAAutoAddPorts.sh script takes care of opening the required ports.

Comment: Looks good, are there any particular modifications of your script required?

Comment: I tried it, but does not work as expected. After I have run the script, the ports were opened, but the dleyna network discovery is somehow slow and unreliable. I guess that there is still missing something because with firewall turned off all works as expected. Of course the application using dleyna have to be restarted.

Comment: I'll take a look into it, for that particular server maybe I need to check for ports that have more than just LISTEN & ESTABLISHED as their status. May take a few days..

Comment: It looks like dleyna is opening/closing ports, possibly during searching far faster than this script could keep up, this is different to the way  minidlna & bubbleupnp work. To 'possibly' fix the problem I'd need to have the script running every 10 seconds maybe even faster and take into account other port statuses so the port isn't closed by the script too soon. Ideally instead of using the cron, I'd need to use inotify to trigger the script then it's response would be much faster. May take more than a few days but I'll let you know.

Comment: I checked the firewall and the ports have to be open before the program start. I have checked it with firewall rules with opening ports from the local dlna server from port 32000 to 55000. Then the network discovery works. Unfortunately there is no reload button on the rhytmbox or totem.

Comment: As it currently works the script won't work reliably with dleyna. I've tried various things including checking every 5 seconds but that still isn't fast enough to open the port before dleyna seems to timeout on that port. As the script is bash it's just not fast enough to open the port sub 1 second, I really need to ditch the polling method and access the /proc/net directly in a C program, only then might it work. Shame as the script works ok for minidlna & bubbleupnp.

Comment: continued.. If I go down that route I'll let you know. Using a 5 second interval does result in all the DLNA devices being discovered intermittently on first opening rhythmbox something it didn't do when the script was running at 30 sec or even 15 sec intervals. You can't run the script any faster than 5 seconds as it takes 3 seconds to complete hence why i need to recode in C.

Comment: @kukulo Hi, any chance you can give the latest version 2.0.14 a try. I've optimised the code so it completes in 0.7s on my I7. If I stop the cron, 'sudo service cron stop' so the version in the cron doesn't run then cd to the directory where you saved the script and type the following while [ 1 ];do ./DLNAAutoAddPorts.sh;sleep 0.1;done

Comment: To reiterate.. sudo bash, then while [ 1 ];do ./DLNAAutoAddPorts.sh;sleep 0.1;done This will run the script almost continuously for this test. With UFW enabled open up Rhythmbox and see if the DLNA devices are found as quick as with the firewall disabled. On my system it works and all the devices appear within a couple of seconds. This suggests as long as the port is opened within a second of dlenya attempting to use it it will work ok. All I need to do then is trigger the script from /proc when a process starts using a port rather than running from crontab. Let me know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: I will try it. Before the ufw log showed a blocked packet from the dlna server on the particular port. So dleyna triggers the dlna server and then the firewall blocks the incoming packet

Comment: the while [ 1 ];do ./DLNAAutoAddPorts.sh;sleep 0.1;done is opening the ports as needed. I guess it opens the port right after the start of the program and before it gets an answer from the dlna server. So far so good. A proc trigger would be better, then we do not need to run the script continuously.

Comment: I've been looking at auditd, redhat developed software, provided in the ubuntu repository. Auditd will give me the notification from the kernel that a request has been made to open a IP4/IP6 socket, I can use that as the trigger, that will make it far more efficient. I'll still need to recode in C as I've been testing with hundreds of ports and the bash script takes way too long to process ie 3-5 seconds. A C program will be so much faster. Luckily I've done a lot of C coding in the past so no learning curve.

Comment: I guess the bash script did it's job in proving it's possible and of course still works fine with the likes of bubbleupnp & minidlna that seem to have bigger timeouts on their socket responses. Now to get down to some C coding ..

Comment: I would rather use a trigger on process start than opening ports and then run the script for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:  `Sudo lsof -i -n -P | more`
This command lists the **Application Name**, **PID**, **User**, IP version, **Device ID** and the **Node with Port Name**. It shows both **TCP** and **UDP**.

- To view only **TCP** connections use:
  `sudo lsof -i tcp -n -P | more`
- To view only **UDP** connections use: `sudo lsof -i udp -n -P | more`
- If you don't have the command available use this command to install **lsof**:
  `sudo apt-get install lsof`

Comment: I have found out that the dleyna-server-service is starting a connection to the same machine: dleyna-se 11031 user  19u  IPv4  98359      0t0  TCP 192.168.99.58:42286 (LISTEN)

Comment: The port is 42286 which needs to be open, but every time I restart the dlna client, the port is different and therefore not predicable. Are there any settings for the dleyna service regarding ports?

Comment: how come you restart the client and the server changes the port??

Comment: check the port in which the server is running, and open the port in your firewall settings.

Comment: The client does not bind to a specific port. Strange is that the client connects to the client machine to 42286 port and then to the server. The server is ok working with another client - android and tv. When I turn on the firewall, then the 42286 port is not shown in the lsof. So the 42286 is connected to the dlna discovery. Each client start changes the port 42286 to something new. Is there any possibility to bind the dleyna service on the client to a specific port?